# views specs failing after upgrade to Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I have a view as follow:

```
json = render 'users/info', user: @user
json[:device] = render 'devices/info', device: @device
json[:locations] = locations.map { |l| render 'locations/info', l: l } if params[:locations_scope].present?

json
```

and I have a test as follow:

```
before do
    product
    assign(:user, user)
    assign(:device, device)
    allow(view).to receive(:user_is_connected?) { false }
    allow(view).to receive(:utc_string)
    render
  end

  describe 'user object' do
    it 'provies the email' do
      expect(subject['user']['email']).to eq(user.email)
    end
```

before upgrade to rails 5, it was working fine, but now I get the error

`@rendered_views=#<ActionView::TestCase::Behavior::RenderedViewsCollection:0x007fd6e8f29a88 @rendered_views={}>> does not implement: user_is_connected?`

the `user_is_connected?` method is a helper method in the base controller.
Seems like this behaviour changed in RoR 5 but I couldn't find anything related to this.

I added `rails-controller-testing` to the gemfile as well, but still, same issue

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out: disable verification of partial mocks on RSpec

```
config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
  mocks.verify_partial_doubles = false
end
```